# Can't resolve all parameters for ObservableDataSource: ([object Object], ?)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I am currently using the [angular material data-table cdk](https://material.angular.io/cdk/table/overview). In order to hook up my ngrx/store into the data-table CDK, I am extending the connect method for the DataSource CDK, to allow for an observable to be injected. The following is the relevant code for this question

```
export class ObservableDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
  private value: any[];
  private key: string;
  constructor(value: any[], key) {
    super();
    this.value = value;
    this.key = key;
  }

  connect() {
    return combineLatest(this.value, (data) => {
      return data[this.key];
    });
  }

  disconnect() {} 
}
```

When unit testing this component(which for curious minds has a `@Component` decorator, just not shown), I receive the following error: 
`Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for ObservableDataSource: ([object Object], ?).`

I then proceeded to provide values for both value and key:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ObservableDataSource ],
      providers:[
        {provide: 'value', useValue: []},
        {provide: 'key', useValue: ''},
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

However, the error `Failed: Can't resolve all parameters..` still shows up. Any suggestions as to how I can properly provide for constructor values, so that Jasmine/Karma can properly resolve parameters is more than appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Does your `ObservableDataSource` actually work? I would think that you would be getting these same errors when trying to use the component in the application, outside of unit tests, too. Injecting values like a string or an array can be done, but you need to use the `@Inject` function to do it. See [here](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injectiontoken).

Comment: It does work. Doing something like the following: `this.dataSource = new ObservableDataSource(this.value, 'visible');` works as expected.

Comment: I see. Then you will have to do the same in the unit tests. Trying to provide the values like you are will not work.

Comment: Ok. So just for curiosity sake, how would I do the same in the unit tests?

Comment: Set a local variable to `new ObservableDataSource(this.value, 'visible');` (change the parameters to what ever is needed), then run your unit tests, `it`/`expect`, against that instance of the component.

Comment: Should I use the native Angular TestBed utility?

Comment: You don't have to. [Here](https://angular.io/guide/testing#service-tests) is something to look at to get an idea of what I mean. The example is testing a service, but the idea is still the same; you would include your params when new'ing up the component.

Comment: Perfect. Will look into specific benefits of testbed and jot down as an answer why that does not make sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking into it a bit more, I did the following to make it work. First, I realized that this is a service, not a component. So i switched over my `@Component()` decorator for `@Injectable`. 
Second, I provided the service with a value of the constructed service as follows:

```
providers: [
   {provide: ObservableDataSource, useValue: new ObservableDataSource([], 'visible')}
]
```

This solved the above issue, and allowed me to continue using TestBed.